# How to limit levels of link that Scrapy crawler?

Tags: scrapy

For this example code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

If I the crowler to visit at most 3 levels of links, how to restrict that? Not the total number of links visited, but the level of links relative to the initial link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DEPTH_LIMIT` setting](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#depth-limit) in your spider in order to limit depth
of crawl:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]
    custom_settins = {
        `DEPTH_LIMIT`:3
    }
    ...
```